# PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase class is not available. Fix... - Makegood , Eclipse

Tags: php, eclipse, phpunit, xdebug, makegood

I am working in OSX 10.11

I am trying to setup PHPUnit , MAKEGood  and Xdebug with Eclipse .

XDebug is Done .
I can Run PHPUnit tests form the console .

But now configuring MakeGood is lot more harder  than i expected .

MY PHP Executables

[image]

Do i have to add pear in `Eclipse->Preferences->PHP->Libraries` ??  i am not sure because i installed PHPUnit using Brew.

```
brew install homebrew/php/phpunit
```

But again i tried to include PEAR .

I gave the path as `usr/local/bin` because when i try `which pear` in terminal it will output as

```
/usr/local/bin/pear
```

[image]

And in my project properties under PHP-> include path i added the above PEAR library .

still from Makegood the error comes as

```
PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase class is not available. Fix..
```

I tried a lot of things ,  Ex:-

```
reinstalling pear
rm .metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.dltk.core.index.sql.h2/*
restart Eclipse
Restart Computer
change pear library path
```

Actually i am not sure what i am doing wrong . Even i am not sure i need the pear library .

Any help is appreciated . Thanks in advance .

Comment: brew install homebrew/php/phpunit gave me Error: homebrew/php was deprecated. This tap is now empty and all its contents were either deleted or migrated.

Answer (score 3):

MakeGood and Composer need some fiddling to get them to work see

- https://github.com/piece/makegood/issues/17
- https://github.com/piece/makegood/issues/85

You might want to

1. install phpunit with composer
2. add a file MakeGoodPreload.php as your Preload Script in the MakeGood configuration.
3. add phpunit.xml

More recent PHPUnit releases are optionally done with composer.

First install composer:

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
```

See https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/installation.html

then install phpunit

```
php composer.phar require "phpunit/phpunit=4.8.*"
```

now test from the command line

```
vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit.php test/MakeGoodTest.php
```

using the MakeGoodTest.php file below.
The result should be:

```
PHPUnit 4.8.21 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.
Warning:    Deprecated configuration setting "strict" used

.

Time: 86 ms, Memory: 4.50Mb

OK (1 test, 5 assertions)
```

Recent MakeGood releases support the user of the composer installed phpunit.

In your Eclipse project create a project "makegood" that contains your
composer installation, test/MakeGoodTest.php, MakeGoodPreload.php and phpunit.xml.

Right click properties of the project and go to the "MakeGood" tab.
in the PHPUnit tab add phpunit.xml and in the General Tab set the Preload Script to MakeGoodPreload.php.

Now you should be able to open MakeGoodTest.php in the editor and right click to
get "Run Tests in class ...".

running it should give you:

```
PHPUnit 4.8.21 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.
Warning:    Deprecated configuration setting "strict" used

.

MakeGood
 [x] [32mPush and pop[39m

Time: 192 ms, Memory: 8.75Mb

OK (1 test, 5 assertions)
```

**phpunit.xml**

```
<phpunit backupGlobals="true"
         backupStaticAttributes="false"
         cacheTokens="false"
         colors="false"
         convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
         convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
         convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
         forceCoversAnnotation="false"
         mapTestClassNameToCoveredClassName="false"
         printerClass="PHPUnit_TextUI_ResultPrinter"
         processIsolation="false"
         stopOnError="false"
         stopOnFailure="false"
         stopOnIncomplete="false"
         stopOnSkipped="false"
         testSuiteLoaderClass="PHPUnit_Runner_StandardTestSuiteLoader"
         strict="false"
         verbose="false">
</phpunit>
```

**MakeGoodPreload.php**

```
<?php
// This is a preload script to be used with
// the Eclipse makegood continuous integration plugin
// see https://github.com/piece/makegood/releases
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$loader = require 'vendor/autoload.php';
```

**test/MakeGoodTest.php**

```
<?php
class MakeGoodTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function testPushAndPop()
    {
        $stack = array();
        $this->assertEquals(0, count($stack));

        array_push($stack, 'foo');
        $this->assertEquals('foo', $stack[count($stack)-1]);
        $this->assertEquals(1, count($stack));

        $this->assertEquals('foo', array_pop($stack));
        $this->assertEquals(0, count($stack));
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you very much .  i'll try this :)