# PHPUnit + Composer + MakeGood, PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase class is not available. Fix

Tags: eclipse, phpunit, makegood

I am using Eclipse for PHP Developers, Eclipse Neon Milestone (4.6).

I have succesfully installed PhpUnit with Composer, and it works great from the command line.

I have also installed MakeGood plugin, but a have an error:

[image]

Already tried all the suggestion in [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34132063/phpunit-framework-testcase-class-is-not-available-fix-makegood-eclipse).

Am I missing something? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I realise this is an old question, but it's worthy of an answer.

If you have set up your environment as per the linked answer, add this line to the top of your test case:

```
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
```

This will pull in the PHPUnit class definitions. 
This will also enable auto-complete of test methods (e.g. assertFalse).